# Toolbar in extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have some toolbar in my exts 4 window

```
this.tbar = {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [

                {
                    id: "btnClearFilter",
                    itemId: "btnClearFilter",
                    action: 'delFilter',
                    disabled: true,
                    handler: function (btn, e) {
                        btn.setDisabled(true);
                    }
                },
                '-',
                {
                    text: 'Export',
                    tooltip: 'Export',
                    disabled: false,
                    menu : {
                        items: [{
                            text: 'Export 1'
                            , icon: 'Content/Resources/images/Excel-16.png'
                            , action: 'export'
                        }]
                    }
                }
            ]
        };
```

From controller i can cause action delFilter like this

```
'ns-main-win > toolbar button[action=delFilter]': {
                click: this.delFilter
            },
```

How couse action from menu item?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question ....

Answer (score 0):

I dunno what you mean, you want to trigger the action on delFilter?

```
Ext.getCmp('btnClearFilter').click()
```

Comment: i want something like this in controller'ns-main-win > toolbar menu > menuitem  > button[action=export]': {
                click: this.export
            },

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the menu item an id and then searching using that

```
    '#export'{
        click:this.export 
        }
```